# Powershell GPO Startup Script not working for removing Microsoft store Apps

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-apps, group-policy

I wrote a Powershell Script to delete Microsoft Store Apps which works fine when run manually. However I want to run it as a Startup script via GPO on all computers (Windows 10 Pro) in our domain. For that, I created a group policy and added the script under Computer configuration>Policies>Windows settings>Scripts. There I added the powershell script on the Powershell scripts tab. I also activated Powershell scripts via Computer configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows components>Windows Powershell>Turn on Script Execution>Allow all scripts

I need the script to be run as a startup script (with system privileges) instead of a logon script as not all users have local admin rights. However the startup script doesn't work. A gpresult shows that the GPO is loaded. Is there anything I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

The script:

```
Get-AppxPackage *3dbuilder* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *zunemusic* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *solitairecollection* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *messaging* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *stickynotes* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *bingfinance* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *zunevideo* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *bingnews* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *onenote* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *feedback* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *3dviewer* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *whiteboard* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *windowsphone* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *bingsports* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *soundrecorder* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *bingweather* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *xboxapp* | Remove-AppxPackage
Get-AppxPackage *xing* | Remove-AppxPackage
```